# Inflection point of integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

How to find the find local max, min and inflection points from an integral?
$$
f(x)=\int_0^x\arctan\frac{|t-1|}{t+1}\,dt\qquad x\in[0,2]
$$

Answer (score 1):

By the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus
$$
f'(x)=\arctan\frac{|x-1|}{x+1}\ge0.
$$

$f$ is increasing on $[0,2]$; the miminum is attained at $x=0$ and the maximum at $x=2$.

$f'$ is decreasing on $[0,1]$ and increasing on $[1,2]$. Then $f$ is concave on $[0,1]$ and convex on $[1,2]$. $x=1$ is an inflection point.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand

$$ \tan^{-1}\dfrac{ |x-1|}{x+1} $$

has to go through zero for local max/min and the derivative/slope should be zero for inflection.

Nowhere in the given interval these occur as we can see in its graph also... as monotonous function behavior. They do not exist.